# Is there a way to bypass having a base OS for Virtual Machines such as VMware?

Tags: virtualization

Is there a way to install software like VMware player on your HD and run that software without an Operating System?

Comment: See this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/23738/run-virtual-machines-without-a-host

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You will need something called a "bare-metal/hypervisor-based" virtulisation solution. This runs a basic OS with very little overhead which the Virtulisation Software runs on top of.

The three big ones are:

- VMWare ESX(i)
- Microsoft Hyper-V
- Citrix XenServer

Each have their own upsides and downside, ranging from costs to supported OS's and platforms.

The Wikipedia [Hypervisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) page has the concept in more technical detail.

Comment: Also Xen, which Citrix bases their solution on but which is both Free and free.

Comment: Technically, it's not a "bare metal" solution you are looking for, but rather a hypervisor that installs **without a host partition**. For example, all the above solutions allow you to install the hypervisor *after* you install a host partition.

Comment: @surfasb, you are correct, of course, but I was trying to keep it simple as possible as virtulisation is a confusing enough concept with it's own terminology as well.

Comment: I'll admit that was a nitpick . . .